# Why won't the html sibling elements become the same height?

Tags: html, css, height, parent-child, siblings

**This is my first question on this website, and I'm pretty much a newbie when it comes to web development, so sorry in advance if this is an incredible dumb question, but I cannot, for the life of me, figure this out:

First of all, here's my html code, simple enough:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <title>TEST</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body class="flexbox">
         <section id="navbar" class="flexbox">
            <ul>
                <li>Aktuell</li>
                <li>Schauspiel</li>
                <li>Projekte</li>
                <li>Gallerie</li>
                <li>Personalien</li>
                <li>Blog</li>
                <li>Links</li>
                <li>Kontakt</li>
                <li>Impressum</li>
            </ul>
         </section>
         <section id="content" class="flexbox">
            <article id="reel">
                <img src="src/img/istockphoto.jpg" alt="Laechelnde Frau">
            </article>
            <article id="quote">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Tempora doloribus commodi aspernatur blanditiis. Nobis optio libero modi reiciendis iusto 
                repellendus harum odit! Natus sed voluptatibus explicabo quo voluptatum eius ab?
            </article>
         </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

**and here is the respective css:**

```
    /* GENERAL*/

    *{box-sizing: border-box;}

    .flexbox{display: flex;}

    html{font-size: .8vw;
         font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         background-color: beige;}

    body{width: 100%;
         margin: 0;
         flex-direction: row;
         align-items: stretch;}

         @media(max-width:425px){#body{flex-direction: column;
                                    align-items: center;}}

    /* NAVIGATION */

    #navbar{background-color: palegreen;
            width: 10%;
            height: 100%;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: stretch;}

            @media(max-width:1024px){#navbar{width:12%;}}
            @media(max-width:768px){#navbar{width:14%;}}
            @media(max-width:425px){#navbar{display: none;}}

    #navbar>ul{list-style-type:none;
               background-color: palegreen;
               padding: 0 0 0 0;
               height: 100%;}

    #navbar>ul>li{display:block;
                  font-size: 1.5rem;
                  width: auto;
                  padding: 15% 15% 15% 15%;}

                  @media(max-width:1024px){#navbar>ul>li{font-size: 1.8rem;}}
                  @media(max-width:768px){#navbar>ul>li{font-size: 2rem;}}

    /* CONTENT */

    #content{width: 90%;
             height: 100%;
             flex-direction: column;}

             @media(max-width:1024px){#content{width:88%;}}
             @media(max-width:768px){#content{width:86%;}}
             @media(max-width:425px){#content{width:100%;}}

    #reel{width:60%;
          margin: 7% auto 0 auto;}

          @media(max-width:768px){#reel{width:70%;}}
    

    #reel>img{width:100%;
              border-radius: 10px;}

    #quote{width:60%;
           background-color: palegreen;
           border-radius: 10px;
           font-size: 1.2rem;
           font-style: italic;
           text-align: center;
           line-height: 150%;
           margin: 5% auto 2% auto;
           padding: 1%}

           @media(max-width:1024px){#quote{font-size: 1.5rem;}}
           @media(max-width:768px){#quote{font-size: 2rem;
                                    width:70%;}}
           @media(max-width:425px){#quote{font-size: 3.3rem;}}
           @media(max-width:375px){#quote{font-size: 3.5rem;}}
           @media(max-width:320px){#quote{font-size: 4rem;}}
```

**What I want to happen is for the section#navbar to always be the exact same height as the section#content, both 100% of the display. So, what I tried is giving both of them 100% height of their parent-element, the body-element.

The problem is that the green background of section#navbar and/or section#navbar>ul just will not stretch to the bottom at the same level as its sibling-element section#content despite both inheriting the same height from their parent-element.

section#content being taller, it should be the one to define the overall height of both sibling-elements as well as the parent-element body, considering the latter has no specific height itself and should therefore be just as high as it needs to be to display all of its child-elements.

(I started out with the body-element also having height:100%; which kind of fixed this specific problem to a degree, but caused even weirder ones I didn't understand, especially when any elements were not entirely within the viewport, so I scrapped it. I also tried using vh as a unit for the different elements' height-property, but that led to pretty much the same chaos. I also tried giving section#navbar and section#navbar>ul the .flexbox-class and a few different properties, none of which worked.)

I assume I'm screwing up something with the position-property as I still cannot wrap my head around how it works and therefore haven't defined it for any elements. But I have tried that as well, giving several of the elements involved different position-properties, none of which helped. I also don't really understand floats, so those haven't been used either.**

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* GENERAL*/

    *{box-sizing: border-box;}

    .flexbox{display: flex;}

    html{font-size: .8vw;
         font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         background-color: beige;}

    body{width: 100%;
         margin: 0;
         flex-direction: row;
         align-items: stretch;}

         @media(max-width:425px){#body{flex-direction: column;
                                    align-items: center;}}

    /* NAVIGATION */

    #navbar{background-color: palegreen;
            width: 10%;
            /*height: 100%;*/
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: stretch;}

            @media(max-width:1024px){#navbar{width:12%;}}
            @media(max-width:768px){#navbar{width:14%;}}
            @media(max-width:425px){#navbar{display: none;}}

    #navbar>ul{list-style-type:none;
               background-color: palegreen;
               padding: 0 0 0 0;
               height: 100%;}

    #navbar>ul>li{display:block;
                  font-size: 1.5rem;
                  width: auto;
                  padding: 15% 15% 15% 15%;}

                  @media(max-width:1024px){#navbar>ul>li{font-size: 1.8rem;}}
                  @media(max-width:768px){#navbar>ul>li{font-size: 2rem;}}

    /* CONTENT */

    #content{width: 90%;
             height: 100%;
             flex-direction: column;}

             @media(max-width:1024px){#content{width:88%;}}
             @media(max-width:768px){#content{width:86%;}}
             @media(max-width:425px){#content{width:100%;}}

    #reel{width:60%;
          margin: 7% auto 0 auto;}

          @media(max-width:768px){#reel{width:70%;}}
    

    #reel>img{width:100%;
              border-radius: 10px;}

    #quote{width:60%;
           background-color: palegreen;
           border-radius: 10px;
           font-size: 1.2rem;
           font-style: italic;
           text-align: center;
           line-height: 150%;
           margin: 5% auto 2% auto;
           padding: 1%}

           @media(max-width:1024px){#quote{font-size: 1.5rem;}}
           @media(max-width:768px){#quote{font-size: 2rem;
                                    width:70%;}}
           @media(max-width:425px){#quote{font-size: 3.3rem;}}
           @media(max-width:375px){#quote{font-size: 3.5rem;}}
           @media(max-width:320px){#quote{font-size: 4rem;}}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <title>TEST</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body class="flexbox">
         <section id="navbar" class="flexbox">
            <ul>
                <li>Aktuell</li>
                <li>Schauspiel</li>
                <li>Projekte</li>
                <li>Gallerie</li>
                <li>Personalien</li>
                <li>Blog</li>
                <li>Links</li>
                <li>Kontakt</li>
                <li>Impressum</li>
            </ul>
         </section>
         <section id="content" class="flexbox">
            <article id="reel">
                <img src="src/img/istockphoto.jpg" alt="Laechelnde Frau">
            </article>
            <article id="quote">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Tempora doloribus commodi aspernatur blanditiis. Nobis optio libero modi reiciendis iusto 
                repellendus harum odit! Natus sed voluptatibus explicabo quo voluptatum eius ab?
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Tempora doloribus commodi aspernatur blanditiis. Nobis optio libero modi reiciendis iusto 
                repellendus harum odit! Natus sed voluptatibus explicabo quo voluptatum eius ab?
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Tempora doloribus commodi aspernatur blanditiis. Nobis optio libero modi reiciendis iusto 
                repellendus harum odit! Natus sed voluptatibus explicabo quo voluptatum eius ab?
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Tempora doloribus commodi aspernatur blanditiis. Nobis optio libero modi reiciendis iusto 
                repellendus harum odit! Natus sed voluptatibus explicabo quo voluptatum eius ab?
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Tempora doloribus commodi aspernatur blanditiis. Nobis optio libero modi reiciendis iusto 
                repellendus harum odit! Natus sed voluptatibus explicabo quo voluptatum eius ab?
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Tempora doloribus commodi aspernatur blanditiis. Nobis optio libero modi reiciendis iusto 
                repellendus harum odit! Natus sed voluptatibus explicabo quo voluptatum eius ab?
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Tempora doloribus commodi aspernatur blanditiis. Nobis optio libero modi reiciendis iusto 
                repellendus harum odit! Natus sed voluptatibus explicabo quo voluptatum eius ab?
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Tempora doloribus commodi aspernatur blanditiis. Nobis optio libero modi reiciendis iusto 
                repellendus harum odit! Natus sed voluptatibus explicabo quo voluptatum eius ab?
            </article>
         </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

You should be able to just leave out that `height` property on the `navbar` id. The flexbox handles that height automatically because of stretching.